# How to send an ordered broadcast in a PendingIntent?

Tags: android, android-pendingintent

I want to send an ordered broadcast in a PendingIntent. But I've only found `PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, intent, 0)`, which I think can only send a regular broadcast. So, what can I do?

Answer (score 4):

I got this from http://justanapplication.wordpress.com/tag/pendingintent-getbroadcast:

> If the onFinished argument is not null then an ordered broadcast is performed.

So you might want to try calling [PendingIntent.send](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/PendingIntent.html#send%28android.content.Context,%20int,%20android.content.Intent,%20android.app.PendingIntent.OnFinished,%20android.os.Handler%29) with the onFinished argument set.

However, I ran into the problem that I had to send an OrderedBroadcast from a Notification.
I got it working by creating a BroadcastReceiver which just forwards the Intent as an OrderedBroadcast. I really don't know whether this is a good solution.

So I started out by creating an Intent which holds the name of the action to forward to as an extra:

```
// the name of the action of our OrderedBroadcast forwarder
Intent intent = new Intent("com.youapp.FORWARD_AS_ORDERED_BROADCAST");
// the name of the action to send the OrderedBroadcast to
intent.putExtra(OrderedBroadcastForwarder.ACTION_NAME, "com.youapp.SOME_ACTION");
intent.putExtra("some_extra", "123");
// etc.
```

In my case I passed the PendingIntent to a Notification:

```
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intent, 0);
Notification notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
        .setContentTitle("Notification title")
        .setContentText("Notification content")
        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.notification_icon)
        .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
        .build();
NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager)context
    .getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
notificationManager.notify((int)System.nanoTime(), notification);
```

Then I defined the following receivers in my Manifest:

```
<receiver
    android:name="com.youapp.OrderedBroadcastForwarder"
    android:exported="false">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.youapp.FORWARD_AS_ORDERED_BROADCAST" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
<receiver
    android:name="com.youapp.PushNotificationClickReceiver"
    android:exported="false">
    <intent-filter android:priority="1">
        <action android:name="com.youapp.SOME_ACTION" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Then the OrderedBroadcastForwarder looks as follows:

```
public class OrderedBroadcastForwarder extends BroadcastReceiver
{
    public static final String ACTION_NAME = "action";

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
    {
        Intent forwardIntent = new Intent(intent.getStringExtra(ACTION_NAME));
        forwardIntent.putExtras(intent);
        forwardIntent.removeExtra(ACTION_NAME);

        context.sendOrderedBroadcast(forwardIntent, null);
    }
}
```